# Bad access error in EAGLView.mm

Tags: ios, cocos2d-x, exc-bad-access, eaglview, cocos2d-x-2.x

I'm getting a weird error in my game.

EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x1) in EAGLView.mm line 319

```
if(![context_ presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER])  ***Error
{
//         CCLOG(@"cocos2d: Failed to swap renderbuffer in %s\n", __FUNCTION__);
}
```

Here's the stack trace

[image: Stack Trace]

The error seems to occur both randomly and after I resume from my pause menu. My pause system simply hides/shows the UI and pauses/resumes the action manager though so I don't know how this could affect it. My game is very simple and i'm not doing anything with view controllers. Other than basic sprites I'm doing just a few opengl renders myself and some custom particle systems. Why might this be occuring? I'd be happy to supply any more information. I'm using cocos2d-x v2.1

Thanks in advance!

Comment: were you able to solve this issue? I have the same. It randomly happens. Thanks.

Comment: I was somewhat able to solve it, I determined that I was adding/removing childs when I apparently wasn't supposed to, causing this error. I could not really understand why.